# How to bring variables into functions - Python

Tags: python, function, variables

I am having an issue where I want to bring a variable into a function by name.

I have tried this so far:

```
x = 5
def func(y = x):
    return y ** 2

>>>print func()
25
>>>x = 4
>>>print func()
25
```

However if I try to edit that input variable after I input the code the number the function detects the old input so it would still print 25 as oppose to the new input squared.

Is there a cleaner way to pull a variable into a function that actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default functions values are calculated during function creation time, so even if you change the value of `x` it is not going to be changed in the function.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> **Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is
>   executed**. This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the
>   function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used
>   for each call.

**Read:** Using `mutable` objects as default value can [lead to unexpected results.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

If you want to access a global value then simply do:

```
def func():
    return x**2
```

Or better pass it explicitly:

```
def func(y):
   return y**2
```

[Another reason why not to use global variables inside function](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value):

```
>>> x = 10
>>> def func():
...     print x
...     x = 5
...     
>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    func()
  File "<ipython-input-5-ab38e6cadf6b>", line 2, in func
    print x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

---

Using `classes`:

```
class A:
    x = 5
    @staticmethod
    def func():
        return A.x**2
...     
>>> A.func()
25
>>> A.x = 10
>>> A.func()
100
```

Comment: But is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could reference global variables in functions. Would +rep but I can't.

Comment: @deadfire19 Yes you can access global variables inside a function, but usually its not recommended. It's better to pass it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the global variable directly, instead of using it as the default value of an argument.

```
def func():
    return x ** 2
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, first time using this site.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of y is set during function definition, not when running it. So default value for `y` is set to value of `x` on `def` line.

This should work:

```
def func(y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = x
    return y ** 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in python Keyword Arguments are always assigned a value and you cant change that assigned value . So in your code

```
x=5
def func(y = x):
    return y ** 2
print func()
x=4
print func()
```

For the keyword argument y the value of x i.e 5 is assigned and we cant change that value. So even if you change the value of x you will get the same output as 25

To solve this the function might directly access the global variable and return the value like the below code

```
x=5
def func():
   return x ** 2
print func()
x=4
print func()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do this

```
x=5
def foo():
    global x
    return x**2
```

Or you can simply do it like this

```
x=5
def foo():
    return x**2
```

In this case the same global variable is referenced if it exists.